# Variable INT, getter DOUBLE

Tags: kotlin, getter

Is it possible to set a getter in kotlin to return a double insted of an int if a variable is an int?

Without declaring a new function ofcourse.

```
var x = 0
    get() = x.toDouble()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to expose a variable as a different type than it actually is, you'll need a [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties):

```
private var _x = 0

val x: Double
    get() = _x.toDouble()
```